# Switch execution contexts in CLR without additional threads to get rid of callbacks

Tags: multithreading, callback, clr

I'm writing a .NET wrapper to a C++ lib for accessing custom DB. The lib uses callbacks to return data queried.

```cpp
void Query(Params p, Func callback);
```

It calls specified function for every record in returned dataset.

I need to write an interface like so:

```
Record ReadOne();
```

It's supposed to block until it gets one record and then return.

To my understanding, such a method should run until library calls back, then freeze this execution and switch context to return single record. On next call to `ReadOne()` it should switch back and return from callback.

I could see this done with additional thread. My question is: could it be done without additional thread? Are there any context manipulation mechanisms in CLR? Could async/await serve this purpose?

Comment: Sounds to me like "freeze this execution" is the hard part. How exactly do you expect that to work? If you mean block in `callback` until released, then you'll need to use a thread for that - the thread that is blocked.

Comment: Suppose that `Query` executes callback asynchronously, otherwise what would be the point. If yes, you can use `TaskCompletionSource` which would set result on a task upon callback execution. Then you can make your method  like `Task<Record> ReadOne();` to await on it. The rest will be done by `async`/`await` mechanism.